# how to define a CRON job to block users after n days?

Tags: strapi

I am really confused documents do not help much. How to disable users programmatically?

I think it must be related to: 
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/users-permissions.html#user-object-in-strapi-context

```js
module.exports = {
   // Every monday at 1am.
  '0 0 1 * * 1': () => {
    // BLOCK USERS CREATED 30 DAYS AGO
  },
};
```

Comment: The more useful approach is typically to do a check during login whether the account is older than a certain time…?!

Comment: Yes as @deceze highlighted, it's better to check during login. Can anyone have an idea how to make such a check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @deceze about checking the user during login to validate their account has not "expired".

Alternatively, as I mentioned in the Strapi slack you can have the cron check for users and set them as blocked using the internal API:

```js
let today = new Date();

let blockedUsers = await strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').find({ "blockDate_lte": today});

blockedUsers.forEach((user) => { strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').update({ id: user.id }, { blocked: true}));
```

Comment: You may need to check what format the `Date()` function gives and instead construct your own to ensure Strapi accepts it

Comment: I think I will ask another question for solution @deceze highlighted.